# I have a flask code that displays "hello world". Why does this code not work when inside main()? Thanks

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

*displays "hello world"*

```
def main():
    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        return "<h1>hello world</h1>"
```

*calls main() here*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Actually you don't need to explicitly call this function like you provided `main()`. so remove this line from your code `main()`
2. try this in terminal
   `export FLASK_ENV=development`

Answer (score 0):

When run as a script: It does not work, because `main()` (where your view function is defined) is called after `app.run()`.

When imported: It does not work, because `main()` is not called at all.

Try this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "<h1>hello world</h1>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```